# Lower semicontinuity of $\lambda f$ when $\lambda >0$.

Tags: real-analysis

I must prove one of the properties in the theorem of lower semicontinuity:

Let $\lambda >0$, if $f$ is lower semicontinuous at $a$, then $\lambda f$ is also lower semicontinuous at $a$.

I am not sure how to start this.

(Definition: $f$ is lower semicontinuous at $a$ if for all $\epsilon >0$, there is $\delta>0$ so that $f(x) > f(a) - \epsilon$ whenever $|x-a|<\delta$.)

Comment: Start by a better description of your question, with fewer abbreviations. How is that $c>0$ relevant for your question?

Comment: Can you write down what it means for $f$ to be lsc at $a$ first?

Comment: f is lower semicontinuous at a if for all epsilon > 0 there exists delta > 0 such that f(x) > f(a) - epsilon when |x-a| < delta

Comment: Do you know what you need to do here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $f$ is lower semicontinuous at $a$, for each $\frac{\epsilon}{\lambda} > 0$, there is a $\delta > 0$ such that $f(x) > f(a) - \frac{\epsilon}{\lambda}$. Multiplying both sides by $\lambda $ on the above inequality yields the result.